# Spring Boot - OAuth with LDAP for authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, ldap

I need to create an AuthorizationServer to handle OAuth2 requests using the **client_credentials** grant type. Client authentication needs to be done using **LDAP**. I've been unable to get all of the pieces working correctly together.

Here is one version of code that I've tried:

application.yml

```
logging:
 level:
   org.springframework.security: DEBUG
server:
 port: 8080

ldap:
  ... omitted ...
```

Main app class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
public class AuthServer
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                SpringApplication.run(AuthServer.class, args);
        }

        private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(AuthServer.class);

        @RequestMapping("/user")
        public Principal user(Principal user)
        {
                logger.info("/user has been called");
                logger.debug("user info: " + user.toString());
                return user;
        }
}
```

OAuth configuration - note that this in-memory ClientDetailsService is only for demo purposes - I will swap this out with an impl that gets details from LDAP later.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter
{
        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception
        {
                clients.inMemory()
                        .withClient("client")
                        .secret("password")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials")
                        .scopes("read", "write");
        }
}
```

If I use the following config for LDAP, the LDAP authentication provider is not actually being used, i.e. the basic auth that occurs when accessing /oauth/token uses the ClientDetailsService, not the LDAP provider.

```
@Configuration
public class LdapConfig extends
        GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter
{
        @Value("${ldap.url}")
        private String url;
        @Value("${ldap.username}")
        private String username;
        @Value("${ldap.password}")
        private String password;
        @Value("${ldap.search_filter}")
        private String searchFilter;
        @Value("${ldap.domain}")
        private String domain;

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
        {
                auth.ldapAuthentication().userSearchFilter(
                        searchFilter)
                        .contextSource().url(url)
                        .managerDn(username)
                        .managerPassword(password);
        }
}
```

But, calls to /user with the token returned from /oauth/token work as expected.

Now, if I change the LDAP config like below (manually configuring the HttpSecurity), then the basic auth filter correctly uses the LDAP provider for authentication when accessing /oauth/token. However, calls to /user no longer attempt to validate the token - I believe due to the fact that the OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter is missing from the filter chain. I receive a 401 "Full authentication is required to access this resource" error.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class LdapConfig2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
        @Value("${ldap.url}")
        private String url;
        @Value("${ldap.username}")
        private String username;
        @Value("${ldap.password}")
        private String password;
        @Value("${ldap.search_filter}")
        private String searchFilter;
        @Value("${ldap.domain}")
        private String domain;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
                http.csrf().disable();
                http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
                http.httpBasic();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
        {
                auth.ldapAuthentication().userSearchFilter(
                        searchFilter)
                        .contextSource().url(url)
                        .managerDn(username)
                        .managerPassword(password);
        }
}
```

And I have tried dozens of variations of those configs. What configuration am I missing that would allow me to have an AuthroizationServer, that is also a ResourceServer, utilizing LDAP for client authentication?

Comment: @dur, it's really the DaoAuthenticationProvider which, as it's way of authenticating, loads the client info using the ClientDetailsService and attempts to match the password returned with the password sent in the request. I don't think that can work with LDAP since I won't have access to a password. So it must be changed at a higher level, i.e. I need an AuthenticationManager that uses an LDAP auth provider instead of one that uses the DaoAuthenticationProvider. I get that with my LdapConfig2 version above but that then leads to the 401 error when accessing resources.

Comment: Ok. The problem is, that your `LdapConfig2` configuration is always applied (highest order). You have to change the request path matcher to not match the resource server's URLs.

Comment: Thanks @dur, I actually realized that late Friday but didn't have time to update here. I unfortunately played around with adding an antMatcher but did it at the wrong place - the authorizeRequests() level - instead of at the top-level request path matcher. If you want to add the solution as an answer here, I'll accept it. Thank you for the help.